# How to set a custom error message on springmvc @RequestParam date

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have a method on a rest service defined like this:

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> methodName(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date date,
```

)

When the date parameter is set to an invalid date such as 2020-3-999, the response from the service is:

> {
>       "status": "error",
>       "message": "Malformed request" }

I need a way to customize what appears in the "message" field of this return message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Custom Error Handling class which should be annotated with @ControllerAdvice and extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

Inside the class you can handle the exception that is occurred in your scenario and respond with a custom Error message.

Refer to https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api for implementation details.

Comment: but how to make it specific for @DateTimeFormat ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take RequestParam input in string and then covert it to date object.
If format is wrong you can easily return your customized output.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be a convenience annotation to make this a no-code solution, similar to: @Min(value=0, message = "Value must be greater than or equal to 0.")